# how can i call a tolist () method in actionresult of controller

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

How can i call the below list method in a ActionResult of a controller

```
public StudRes<List<Student>> GetStudent()
{
    Database SQLCon = new Database();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    string query = @"select s.items StudentName from StudentData t1 outer apply dbo.Split(t1.StudentName, ',') s";

    dt = SQLCon.getDatatableFromSQL(query);

    return new LinkRes<List<Student>>()
    {
        result = dt.dtHavingRow(),
        data = (from rw in dt.AsEnumerable()
                select new Student
                {
                    StudentName= rw["StudentName"].ToString(),
                }).ToList()
     };
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult StudentCode()
{
    var _Student = new StudRes<List<Student>>();
    var _StudentInfor = new StudentInfor ();
    StudAct _Act = new StudAct();
    _Student = _Act.GetStudent(Cookies.GetCookies("StudentName"));
    _StudentInfor = _Act.GetStudentInfor(Cookies.GetCookies("StudentName"));
    string stud = String.Foramt(_Student.StudentName,_StudentInfor.Email);
}
```

For "_Student.StudentName" shows error

> CS1061: StudRes> does not contain a definition for
>   'StudentName' and no extension method 'StudentName' accepting a frist
>   argument of type 'StudRes>' could be found (are you
>   missing  a using directive or an assembly reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you need is to return only 1 student instead of the list.  You may want to rework your GetStudent method.  Otherwise, as things stand, on the controller, `_Student.data.First().StudentName` should work.  Also, in your GetStudent Method you have a typo `SrudentName= rw["StudentName"].ToString()` should be  `StudentName= rw["StudentName"].ToString()`

Edit 1.

```
public class Student
    {
        public string StudentName { get; set; }
        public string StudentEmail { get; set; }
    }

    public StudRes<List<Student>> GetStudents()
    {
        Database SQLCon = new Database();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        string query = @"select s.items StudentName from StudentData t1 outer apply dbo.Split(t1.StudentName, ',') s";

        dt = SQLCon.getDatatableFromSQL(query);

        var results = new StudRes<List<Student>>()
        {
            result = dt.Rows.Count,
            data = (from rw in dt.AsEnumerable()
                    select new Student
                    {
                        StudentName = rw["StudentName"].ToString(),
                    }).ToList()
        };
        foreach (var stu in results.data)
        {
            stu.StudentEmail = GetStudentInfor(stu.StudentName);
        }
        return results;
    }

 public ActionResult StudentCode()
        {
            StudAct _Act = new StudAct();
            var _Student = _Act.GetStudents();

            return View("Name of your view", _Student.ToList());
        }
```

Comment: What if i need to return the list, how should i call the result in the controller

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do, but I made a suggestion on how to retrieve a list of StudRes in the controller.  Please see Edit 1.

Comment: Great thanks with your answer above. what i want to achieve is to display the result data from the .ToList Method